# Is my computer part of a botnet? (based on 4 symptoms)

Tags: windows-7, boot, freeze, malware, upload

I have four signals that, together, hint to the fact that something is going on on my machine (windows 7 x64, Precision M4600 from 2011):

1. The black windows startup screen lasts for 50 seconds, although it used to take less than 15 when the computer was new
2. although Firefox and flash player have been updated several times during that period of time, Firefox has been freezing for 1-6 sec repeatedly for a month now, every now and then, mostly when I open a new tab, even when flash player plug-in is not loaded
3. Kasperksy security scan (last version, freshly downloaded) won't start (several instances of the process in the task manager, three at first, when I close them all and try to restart it, I get only one but it shows the "hourglass circle" next to the mouse for 0.2 s every 1 s while doing nothing special)
4. my upload speed has gone down from about 0.8 to 0.45 Mbit/s, though fluctuating on the time scale of seconds. Upload from other places also seems a bit random.

All of this together with a general ever so slight sluggishness of the computer

I didn't have time yet to start the extended procedure ("war") against this, but I wanted to know your point of view on those four symptoms? I will try some tools, and if everything fails, fortunately I can do a fresh system reinstall in my case (although it will take me quite some time).

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Download Avast / Avira Rescue Disk and do a offline (boot) scan

Comment: try everything with your computer not connected to the internet

Comment: [Download the Kaspersky rescue Boot disk and do an offline scan](http://support.kaspersky.com/4162)